# Setting a rate of fire for a weapon - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have only just started trying to develop a game in Unity and only have about 7 months of coding experience, so any help would be appreciated.

As the title says, I am trying to set a rate of fire for a weapon in this game and here is my code.

```
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _arrowPrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private float _fireRate = 1f;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool allowFire = false;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        fireArrow(); 
    }

    public void fireArrow()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && allowFire)
        {
            StartCoroutine(FireRate());
        }

        IEnumerator FireRate()
        {
            allowFire = false;
            Instantiate(_arrowPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_fireRate);
            allowFire = true;
        }
    }


}
```

So if I run the code as is, the weapon doesn't fire. If I check the allowFire box in the Unity engine and set the boolean to true, it fires as intended in one second intervals. But if I go back into the code and set the boolean to true initially, the weapon doesn't fire.

I am assuming it is something small that I am missing but my searches have only resulted in me finding code that looks exactly like mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `allowFire` boolean is being serialized.

This means that Unity Editor has cached the value for that field, and will use it as the default value, disregarding what your constructor or default values from the class set those fields to.

This is desired behaviour, since you may have had INTENTIONALLY set the value to false, because, say, you didn't want the weapon fire to be allowed on the beginning of the game.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the quick response. This information will be very useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Inspector is playing with you :)

Public fields are serialized automatically, your private "allowFire" is serialized by [SerializeField] - so it is exposed in Inspector, and as you already noticed, you can change values in the Inspector.

Unity will remember the first value from script (false) and save it (serialize it) in Inspector. This is useful especially if you have multiple GameObjects, because you can set different values independent of the value in script.

This means, you can change the variable to "true" **in code** but Inspector will **overwrite/replace** this using the serialized value.

You have multiple options:

- Set the value to true in `Start()`
- Click the 3 Dots on the right at the Script-Component (Inspector) and choose **Reset**
- Just tick the Checkbox when the game is not running to make Unity serialize the "true" state.

Many people fell for this. Just remember: Changes in Code on public/serialized fields are replaced by Inspector, and will seem like changing your code "does nothing".

Comment: Thank you! Fixed it instantly. I will keep this in mind in the future.